# sr-only not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

I have a live region where a button when clicked increments the count value displayed(similar to votes/likes). The message to be read out by the screen reader is a computed value, example: "1 person likes this article"/"No one has liked this article"/"8 people like this article". These messages are computed in the client *script(count value)* and defined in the server *script(final message)*.

```
<div class="sr-only" role="alert" aria-live="polite">

   <span id="feedback-count">{{c.message}} /span>

</div>
```

This works perfectly in chrome but doesn't read out the message in IE in Windows using Jaws screen reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few approaches and this one works best for me, Fixed the issue and the screen reader text was read out perfectly in all browsers.

```js
functionToBeCalled = function(message) {
    aria_message = message;
  document.getElementById('screen-reader-tag-id').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('screen-reader-tag-id').innerHTML += '<p class="sr-only">'+ aria_message+'</p>'
 }
```

```html
<div id="screen-reader-tag-id" class="sr-only" role="alert" aria-live="polite">
  </div>
```